# How to get a file from storage with special characters

Tags: android, file, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to read a file (PDF) from my storage in android. The path is correct, but when i try to open the file, i get a message that says that file is not found, but i know that the file is there. When files that do not have special characters (accents) i have no problem.

When i go see the file in storage, it appears with two weird characters instead of "á".
I dont even know how to write the first one, but its something like an ASCII character and the other is "ü".

Any solutions?

[image]

Thats the name of the file in my files viewer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there was a bug reported against JVM and Android as well. i think it is fixed now.

I can suggest to use this method to get the file name or try other UTF encoded string instances

```
byte[] textArray = f.getName().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

I didn't test this but just a suggestion since you didn't provide how you did read the filename. and also please make sure you do the file existence if condition before you read the filename.